# Who is the intended audience of Matthew 5-7?

Tags: matthew, sermon-on-the-mount

Matthew 5 begins:

> <sup>1</sup>Seeing the crowds, he went up on the mountain, and when he sat down, his disciples came to him.
>
> <sup>2</sup>And he opened his mouth and taught ***them***, saying: <sub><sub>[ESV](http://www.esvbible.org/Matthew+5%3A1-2)</sub></sub>

and Matthew 7 ends:

> <sup>28</sup>And when Jesus finished these sayings, the crowds were astonished at his teaching, <sup>29</sup>for he was teaching them as one who had authority, and not as their scribes. <sub><sub>[ESV](http://www.esvbible.org/Matthew+7%3A28-29)</sub></sub>

The 'them' in Matthew 5:2 is perhaps ambiguous but is usually taken to mean the disciples, but by the end, it is 'the crowds' who Jesus 'was teaching'. Were the crowds just 'overhearing' teaching directed at the disciples? Were the disciples and the crowds both being addressed all along? Was there a gradual shift in audience, or a point in the teaching when Jesus starts addressing the wider audience?

---

*<sup>edit in response to Joseph's comment:</sup>*

…or, were 'the crowds' in 7:28 the same people as 'the disciples' in 5:1?

Comment: In [Luke 6:17-49](http://www.bibleserver.com/text/ESV/Luke6:17-49), if Luke is referring to the same events as Matthew 5-7 (i.e., Sermon on the Mount) then the term "disciples" is qualified by Luke in his gospel account as "a large crowd of his disciples" not to mention "a great throng of people" [(Luke 6:17)](http://www.bibleserver.com/text/ESV/Luke6:17). Concerning this large crowd of people, Luke continues and writes: "And turning his gaze toward _his disciples_..." [(Luke 6:20)](http://www.bibleserver.com/text/ESV/Luke6:20). Thus the great mass of people also comprised "his disciples."

Comment: I'd been thinking on the same lines without considering Luke: in some sense at least, the crowd were his 'disciples' as they were following him and listening to his teaching.

Comment: In [John 6:60](http://www.bibleserver.com/text/ESV/John6:60) there is mention of "many of his disciples" which, due to the announcement of carrying ones cross, then becomes a group whittled down to no less than 12 people according to [John 6:66-67](http://www.bibleserver.com/text/ESV/John6:66-67).

Comment: Additionally, your question betrays your bias. Joseph, I was wondering if you'd be willing to interact with other scholarly sources and, perhaps, justify the claim that the sermon on the mount and the sermon on the plain are the same event

Comment: @swasheck Joseph didn't make that claim, did he?

Comment: @swasheck or was "You're supposing that they are the same sermon" directed at me, in which case can you explain what you mean? Also assuming "Additionally, your question betrays your bias" was directed at me, I've tried to edit in a bit more neutrality, but please suggest your own edit: I want the question to be neutral.

Comment: @JackDouglas ... Joseph made the claim in his first paragraph.

Comment: @swasheck I see the word 'if': I don't think it was a claim, logically speaking. A supposal perhaps?

Comment: @JackDouglas i read that "if" as "since" because he went ahead and described the parallels.

Comment: @joseph I believe you're straining the interpretation on Jn 6:66. I don't think that means that only the twelve remained.

Comment: @swasheck it's not much of a leap from verse 70 is it?

Comment: @jackdouglas I question the relevance. I'm just saying that the text of John never limits the group to the twelve. He only specifically addresses the twelve in the setting of John.

Comment: @swasheck (and jackdouglas) - I apologize for the confusion. When I said "no less than 12 disciples" I did not mean that 12 disciples were left, but that numerically the number of people involved at the time did not go below twelve. (In other words, there could have been 50 people remaining.) What I forgot to mention was that the number of disciples following Jesus eventually went to zero according to [**John 16:32**](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=John+16:32&version=NASB).

Comment: which is the name of mountain in Matthew5-7?

Comment: @Jack Douglas, excellent question! I say, your questions have answers that cover pretty much all the bases. They are all Jews, the Abrahamic Covenant Chosen people of God. Jesus was explicit that He came to His own, and they rejected Him, which signifies the Sermon on the mount (Ch. 5-7) was for “His own” (and believers), not for those who do not have ears to hear. I hope that is what you are driving at?

Answer (score 10):

Matthew 5-7 is most naturally read as a single literary unit. Jesus went up to a mountainside and his disciples went with him (Matt. 5:1-2). However, by the end of the discourse we notice that the crowds are amazed by Jesus' teaching. It seems that the crowds found Jesus and the disciples.

I contend that Jesus' ***primary*** audience are his disciples. At this point it is not delineated as to whether or not this means the Twelve, the seventy, or a larger group of disciple. However, I read 5:1 to indicate a withdrawal by Jesus from the larger multitudes. That's not to say that they had nothing to gain from the teaching, but that Jesus was specifically addressing the disciples and the remainder were welcome to listen.

My sense is that the "crowds" serve as a larger people group and are held over against the disciples, however many they are. This would be consistent with Matthew's portrayal of "the crowds" as being a large group of people who were looking for a miracle, or people who were there for the show. I guess I'd call them "potential insiders" but not "insiders" like the disciples.

There are no breaks in the discourse of Matt 5 - 7 that would indicate a shift of attention to this broader audience.

The so-called Sermon on the Plain has too much literary and conceptual overlap to not be describing the same event. Differences between the two are explicable (but that'd be a different question). Luke still has the disciples as his primary audience in his version (Lk. 6:20) but his account reads more along the lines that the crowds had already found them.

So a reasonable timeline would be:

1. Jesus sees the large crowds
2. Jesus withdraws to pray
3. The disciples (apparently a large group) go to find Jesus
4. Jesus talks to his disciples as the crowds find them

Answer (score 0):

There was an article published in the Ensign magazine in 1991 available [online](https://www.lds.org/ensign/1991/03/sermon-of-sermons?lang=eng) that includes the following commentary:

> According to the Book of Mormon account, Jesus addressed different
>   segments of the congregation at different times during the sermon. It
>   is important to note these shifts in audience as we try to apply the
>   meaning of these passages to our individual lives. It is possible that
>   instructions given to a specific portion of the audience are not
>   applicable to the general audience.
>
> One such instance is 3 Nephi 13:25–34 [3 Ne. 13:25–34]. (See also
>   Matt. 6:25–34.) The Book of Mormon account indicates that Jesus
>   concluded one portion of his sermon and then “looked upon the
>   twelve”—those “whom I have chosen to minister unto this people.” Then
>   he began speaking directly to them. (3 Ne. 13:25.) The Matthew account
>   does not make it clear that there is an audience shift, but the
>   account in Luke does. (See Luke 12:22.)
>
> A careful analysis of the verses that follow indicates that these
>   doctrines apply to the unique situation and calling of the Twelve
>   Apostles, who had consecrated their entire lives to the service of the
>   Master and the preaching of his gospel.

It should be noted that the account of the Sermon on the Mount in the Book of Mormon is almost identical to the account in Matthew 5-7 with only a few minor changes for context. In direct answer to your question, in 3 Nephi 12:1 it states "he stretched forth his hand unto the multitude, and cried unto them, saying" showing that the beginning of the sermon is directed to the multitude, but as shown above there is a shift in audience for part of the sermon to be directed at the apostles specifically. Then in 3 Ne 14:1, "when Jesus had spoken these words he turned again to the multitude, and did open his mouth unto them again, saying:" thus the content in Matt 7 was directed back to the multitude.

I know this answer doesn't technically come from the Bible, but I personally have found the correlation between Book of Mormon account and the Bible account beneficial for further edification.

Answer (score -2):

Hello Brothers & perhaps Sisters!!!

Short & simple, JESUS was talking to the crowd & HIS Disciples. The crowd were obviously interested people & not obviously disciples, because the "Great Commission" had not yet been given. JESUS Hand selected his Disciples that HIS FATHER have to HIM. Not to say, that by Faith, many weren't already, but it states plainly... "A crowd gathered to listen" & more than likely, out of intrigue & curiosity!!!

Just my take!!! FATHER, may YOUR HOLY SPIRIT Teach all things!!! In the MIGHTY NAME OF JESUS CHRIST... AMEN!!!

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics Stack Exchange! Be sure to take our [site tour](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn more about us.  We need to answer questions using [references](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/777/2873), a requirement on this site. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics Stack Exchange! I'm very grateful for your participation here, but [this site is a little different from other sites.](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/803/423) I think you can benefit a lot if you see the [kind of answers](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/520/3474) that this site is looking for.